# How to remove data from db using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been trying to implement redux and I can post data into the database using redux, and then fetching the results in react. But I'm having difficulty on how to approach the reducer and implementing a delete case.

I had previously attempted to use a function that would delete data in the database through sqlite, but with mixed results. If my memory serves me correct, I could possibly use a prototype method to remove the data from the database, without mutating the state.

```
 import request from 'superagent'

 export function receiveData(data) {
     return {
         type: 'RECEIVE_DATA',
         payload: data
     }
 }

 export function fetchData() {
     return (dispatch) => {
         request.get('/api/v1/data')
         .then((res) => {
             return res.body
         }).then(data => {
             dispatch(receiveCats(data))
         })
     }
 }


function reducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RECEIVE_DATA':
            return action.payload
        case 'ADD_DATA':
            return action.add
        default:
            return state
    }   
}

// case 'DELETE_CAT':
////// return action.del
// to be added

export default reducer

    export function addData(data) {
        return dispatch => {
            request
            .post('/api/v1/data')
            .send(data)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message)
                    return
                }
                dispatch(addDataAction(data))
            })
        }
    }

    function addDataAction() {
        return {
            type: 'ADD_DATA',
            payload: {
                name: name,
                // age: age,
                // address: address
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to understand how redux works but this a hurdle for me.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is action.add here?

Comment: I suspect it is the payload of data? But I'm quite unsure honestly.

Comment: You said you completed add and update case, so add your code here

Comment: It's better to add a middleware for your dispatched actions and do the db async operation there. Checkout [Epic](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html) or [Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) to get a better ida. Your reducer should not mutate the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have implemented the delete/remove api which returns the deleted the ID

```
  function reducer(state = [], action) {
            switch (action.type) {
                case 'RECEIVE_DATA':
                    return Object.assign({},state, {data:action.payload});
                case 'ADD_DATA':
                    return Object.assign({},state, data.concat(action.add));
                case 'REMOVE_DATA':
                    return Object.assign({},state, 
                   {data:state.data.filter((obj)=>obj.id!==id)});
                default:
                    return state
            }   
        }
```

Try something like this always remember to use the concept of immutability. In this example it will return a new object rather than updating the previous object.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the information. My understanding of state management is not as strong as I would like it to be. But something like this will help me get over the hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misunderstood something. There is nothing called `remove data from db using redux` or `post data into the database using redux`.

What you did in the above example in the `addData` reducer to `post data into the database using redux` is just calling a post request to the server and then save that posted data in [Redux store](https://redux.js.org/api/store).

If you want to delete data from your db, call corresponding `delete api` then save the result of the request in `Redux store`.

Redux is just a place to store your `application state`, that state will decide how the app's UI look.

You can read the [Redux Introduction](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) to understand what Redux is.

Comment: My apologies. My lack of foreknowledge in managing states has been conceptually difficult. Not something I am instantly used to. I have a database setup in my code so I thought my question made sense, but I see now that it did not. Go easy on people like me with a lack of understanding or foreknowledge. Thanks.